# Microsoft Dynamics Entity Form Validation Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am writing my first JavaScript extension in Microsoft Dynamics Customer Engagement, and I can't get my script to work the way I want it. I am trying to check if the country field is empty. If it is, I want to set a notification and make it a required field. If it is not empty and the country is United States, I want to check if state and zip are empty. If they are, I want to set a notification and make them required fields. If the country is not United States, I want to clear the notifications for state and zip. And if the country is United States and state and zip are populated, I want to clear the notifications.

The country field uses a lookup, and I am accounting for that by assigning the country lookup value for the conditional check on state and zip.

I have this set to execute on save. Please see my code below. I have been at this for a while, and it's driving me mad. Any help is appreciated.

And I apologize if this looks like a hot mess right now. I've changed the code about 872 times and finally threw my hands in the air.

```
function SetMandatoryFields(executionContext) {

    debugger;
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var addressState, addressCountry, addressZip, countryLookup;

    //Initialize variables to corresponding form fields. Get value of form fields and set fields to required if applicable.
    addressState = formContext.getAttribute("usf_address1stateid").getValue();
    addressZip = formContext.getAttribute("address1_postalcode").getValue();
    addressCountry = formContext.getAttribute("usf_address1countryid").getValue();

    //If country is United States, set state as required field if it is null or blank, and prompt user for field value. Else, clear prompt.
    if (addressCountry != null && addressCountry != "") {
        formContext.getControl("usf_address1countryid").clearNotification();
        countryLookup = formContext.getAttribute("usf_address1countryid").getValue()[0].name;
        //If country lookup is equal to United States, make state and zip required fields.
        if (countryLookup == "United States") {
            if (addressState == null || addressState == "") {
                formContext.getControl("usf_address1stateid").setNotification("State is a required field.");
            }
            else {
                formContext.getControl("usf_address1stateid").clearNotification();
            }
            if (addressZip == null || addressZip == "") {
                formContext.getControl("address1_postalcode").setNotification("Zip/Postal Code is a required field.");
            }
            else {
                formContext.getControl("address1_postalcode").clearNotification();
            }
        }
        //If country lookup is not United States, remove state and zip requirement
        else if (countryLookup != "United States") {
            
            formContext.getControl("address1_postalcode").clearNotification();
            formContext.getControl("usf_address1stateid").clearNotification();
        }
    }
    else {
        formContext.getControl("usf_address1countryid").setNotification("Country is a required field.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Couple of things to check. Assuming that you are into UCI.
1) You have added this script to your form.
2)  Registered the method "onSave" of form
3)  Passing the executioncontext where the onSave is registered.
4) Did you try to debug and hit your debugger statement?

Comment: Did you test it?

Answer (score 1):

The important snippet to make the fields mandatory is missing, refer the sample changes below and modify your code accordingly.

```
if (addressState == null || addressState == "") {
    formContext.getControl("usf_address1stateid").setNotification("State is a required field.");
    formContext.getAttribute("usf_address1stateid").setRequiredLevel("required");
}
else {
    formContext.getControl("usf_address1stateid").clearNotification();
    formContext.getAttribute("usf_address1stateid").setRequiredLevel("none");
}
```

Comment: agree, personally I think that making the other fields as required when the lookup is United States is enough, notifications are a plus